# Java offset drawing canvas

Tags: java, canvas

I am trying to make a simple java game, and i got stumped on this. The game requires that you play in a square window, but can resize the sprites on the canvas. I though it would be really annoying if I used a ComponentListener and didn't let the user change size, so I thought that I would just offset the canvas from the left and right side so that it is centered until it is square.

Right now I understand that I need to create a Canvas object for the Game, and then offset it but I'm not sure how.
Game Canvas:

```
public class GameCanvas extends Canvas {
    public Vector size;
    public GameCanvas(Vector size) {
        this.size = size;
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setSize(size.x, size.y);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated :) thank you.

Comment: You could: 1- make better use of the layout manager API to ensure that the `Canvas` is always laid out as a square; 2- Generate a virtual concept of the available area within which the game can take place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You could...

Make your own layout manager which maintained the `Canvas` in a square shape based on the available space of the parent `Container`.

This might be a little bit of over kill, but, it's generally more efficient and means you can keep using the properties of the `Canvas` (ie `getWidth` and `getHeight`), so it's more de-coupled from other solutions

## You could...

Calculate a "playable area" based on the size of the `Canvas` and use that as the bounds range checking, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected Rectangle getPlayableBounds() {
            Dimension size = getSize();
            int playableSize = Math.min(size.width, size.height);
            int x = (size.width - playableSize) / 2;
            int y = (size.height - playableSize) / 2;
            return new Rectangle(x, y, playableSize, playableSize);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(getPlayableBounds());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This example is not optimised, as calling `getPlayableBounds` recalculates the playable area, regardless if its changed since the last call or not.

I'd be tempted to use a `ComponentListener` and make the `playableBounds` an instance field.  When the component is resized, I'd simply invalidate the `playableBounds` property, which would force the `getPlayableBounds` to recalculate the value and cache the result

Comment: But how do i offset the canvas?

Comment: I've given you two ideas, which one is more likely to fulfil you needs